# How do I use the LinkedIn API to access my LinkedIn account using a Google Sheet?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, spreadsheet

I would like to be able to use a Google Sheet to access my account and post content to the 95 LinkedIn Groups wherein I am a member.  I have been told I should be able to do such operations using the LinkedIn API, but have no clue as to how to proceed.  Please give me some guidance and direction in this effort.

Comment: You would read the [Google Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) and the [LinkedIn API documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/), discover how the two could be linked, and write some code.

Comment: There is also [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link2sheet-linkedin-to-go/inpcghhelcmfglmbbgjhnhjhjhbnebje?hl=en).

Comment: And [this](https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/linkedin).

Comment: I suppose the first step is the get my LinkedIn API key.  This documentation is somewhat complex for a person who is not a computer programmer.  I would appreciate it if @RobertHarvey would respond to me.  I doubt it is all that complicated to access my own LinkedIn account using a spreadsheet and my LinkedIn API key, but it is virtually impossible if I do not even know how to proceed.